# Plugin to automate multiple searching?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

Is there a Firefox plugin I can use to help automate multiple searches?

i.e. I have a list of keyword combinations and I want to automatically paste each combination into a form like below and open each search in a new tab
http://scholar.google.com/advanced_scholar_search

The actual website I'm using is ISI Web of Science. It has a similar form to Google Scholar, except the form uses POST. Originally I thought about about making a Python script that downloads all search result pages, but POST + paywall authentication makes it complicated to do outside of browser

Comment: I'd do this in Python.  You can also definitely do this in a FF *extension*.  Greasemonkey is problematic because of the requirement to **POST** to a new tab. I can think of a possible approach, but it's not something I can quickly bang out.  However, many websites don't distinguish between GET and POST -- as long as the variables are sent.  Install the *Web Developer Addon* (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/ ) and test your pages with the `Convert Form Methods` -> `POSTs to GETs`. If it works, it makes things much easier.

Comment: It seems to work, but...after converting form methods and getting confirmation, page source still shows "POST" and location bar in the new page doesn't have the field values, is that normal?

Comment: The page-source will always show "POST".  Ideally, the field values should show in the address bar.  But if the server/page redirects or reloads, then it may be immediately rewritten.  Page JS could also force a post.  A packet sniffer would show for sure.   But, if you: (1) Load the page and fill the form, (2) Convert POSTs to GETs, (3) submit... and the page still works, then it's a good sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMacros, started for a clean browser profile - from your program, that also should generate a script (page number, # of blocks to extract). + AutoIT for harsh Flash cases.

There are also Selenium, Greasemonkey, capturing HTTP(s) traffic, anything else?